# How do you determine whether a CSS property requires browser specific prefixes?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I recently looked at the following question:

[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Which nicely provided the answer to the immediate CSS problem I was facing. However, it made me wonder, how do you determine when it is safe to drop all the browser specific prefixes for CSS properties?

I know how the mechanics of this work, older browsers which require a prefix will of course always need a prefix, so I suppose the answer really depends on the browser usage statistics.

Is there a decent, simple, source of reference that can be used to determine whether all these prefixes are really required for a CSS property, e.g. if I use the `user-select` property without prefixes, I can guarantee 95% of browsers will interprit this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) is an excellent summary of browser support for pretty much every CSS property.

However, I tend to use the browser-specific prefixes, as well as the non-specific rule, no matter what - it's not exactly much extra work and it will mean those few people stuck on outdated browsers still see the page as you intended.

Comment: Thanks for the resource you referenced. "not exactly much work" - seriously? repeating each property 5 times over!

Comment: Well, it depends if you want to type 5 properties to potentially reach a wider audience, or risk just going with the one. It's only a small percentage of all properties that require a browser-spcific prefix, so for the ones that do, it's definitely worth the small amount of effort!

Answer (score 1):

One good resource I've used for this sort of thing is http://caniuse.com/. In general, it is not a bad idea to have a list like, for example,

```
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

For the space of a few lines, this ensures that older browsers will get the right browser-specific rules if they require them, and that newer browsers get the standards-compliant rule.

**Edit:** Well, I noticed that the resource to which I linked does not have an entry on user-select. Oops!

Comment: Oops from me too! Just saw your edit and though I'd check the resource I linked to... not there either!

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be the best resource for that:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp